# background images stacking css

Tags: css, wordpress

have a site I am working on wordpress twenty twelve theme; and on a page want to have three background images; one at top, next one right below top one; and then third one at very bottom…

is there anything i can put in "background position" that will make the second image right below the first?  here is what I have:

```
 {background-position: top, ???, bottom;}
```

so I am looking for what to put where the ??? is to make the second image right below the first, can anyone help?

thanks, G

Answer (score 0):

Make 3 content divs, and set them to no margin and the exact height. 
I'm not putting exact code, because I don't know what your height are or image name, but use something like:

```
.Class{
background-image: foo.jpeg;
height: 500px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.Class2{
background-image: foo2.jpeg;
height: 700px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="Class">Text</div>
<div class="Class2">Text bottom</div>
```

You can also set the *z-index* to *-100* and put other divs on top of these, float left, etc.

Comment: I am sorry - i appreciate your help, but that is not what I am looking  for, I edited the question to hopefully be more clear...